# Solving Polar Equations

Tags: trigonometry

How do you solve $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=1.2$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.
Answer in the nearest radian.

I've got...

$\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

$\sin(x)-\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}=1.2$

$(\sin(x)+1.2)^2=(\sqrt{1-\sin^2x})^2$

$\sin^2x+2.4\sin(x)+(1.44-1)=.44$

$\sin^2x+2.4\sin(x)-.44=0$

$2\sin^2x+2.4\sin(x)-.44=0$

$2y^2+2.4y-0.44=0$

I used the quadratic formula after this, but I came up with a number that is larger than 1, so arcsin is not possible.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $(\sin(x) + \cos(x))^2 = 1.2^2$
so
$1 + \sin(2x) = 1.2^2$
so $\sin(2x)=0.44$

Comment: so 0.44 is not negative?

Comment: So there are solutions. I'm not sure what you did but if u get sinx >1 this will give no solutions but you also have another solution probably -1<sinx<1 which gives solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply can be written as 
$$\sqrt2\sin\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr)=1.2\quad\text{or}\quad\sqrt2\cos\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr)=1.2,$$
whence the solutions are
\begin{alignat*}{2}
x&\equiv\begin{cases}
\arcsin\dfrac{3\sqrt2}5-\dfrac\pi4\\
\dfrac{3\pi}4-\arcsin\dfrac{3\sqrt2}5
\end{cases}\mod 2\pi,
&\qquad\text{or}\qquad x\equiv\frac\pi4\pm\arccos\dfrac{3\sqrt2}5\mod2\pi.
\end{alignat*}

Comment: where does the pi/4 come from?

Comment: It's fairly standard: $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\bigl(\sin x\cos\frac\pi4+\cos x\sin\frac\pi4\bigr)$.

Comment: Not really. *This one* is a standard case. The general problem is this: how to write $a\sin x+b\cos x$ as $A\sin(x+\varphi)$, or $A\cos(x+\varphi)$. It is a common problem when you study electric circuits with alternating current.

Comment: Makes sense,thanks.